# WebOS onComplete event or analog

Tags: javascript, onload, webos, enyo, lg

I want call onclick event after form loaded.
I not found onCompletion Event or any analog

something like : `kind: someUI, onComplete: "Init"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure from your description, but it sounds like you want to cause some action to occur when the app is loaded.  You might try using `ready()` as described in the getting started guide.

http://enyojs.com/docs/latest/developer-guide/getting-started/creating-and-building-an-app.html

The other choice is to add something to your initial App `rendered` that executes your `buttonTapped()` method.

```
rendered: function () {
    this.inherited(arguments);
    this.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, you right i need call action after app loaded. I use ready() function but have problem with binding it with components.  I changed question for better understanding.

Comment: Can you give init app render example?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.  I rewrite code like this

```
     {kind: IconButton, src: '@../../assets/info.png', ontap: "buttonTapped"},

create: function() {
                this.inherited(arguments);
                this.ServiceReq();
            },

    buttonTapped: function(inSender, inEvent) {

        this.ServiceReq();  
        return;

    },

    ServiceReq: function()
        { console.log('Clicked');}
```

But I'm not sure this is a good solution, but it works

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you should use [rendered()](http://enyojs.com/docs/latest/#/kind/enyo/Control/Control:rendered).  `create()` is called before components are rendered onto the page so you won't have controls that can respond.  I updated my answer to show `rendered()`